# How can I access a session variable set on page from a different page

Tags: php, session-variables

I've tried looking for information on what I'm trying to do, but the results are not what I'm need to get done. I'm pretty sure there's an answer out there to my issue, but I have no idea how search for it with the correct wording. Anyways what I'm trying to do is: Here I have created a session variable

```
<?php
// Session started
session_start();


// Connecting to the database
$host = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$db_name = "potholio";
$tbl_name = "userTbl";

$conn = mysql_connect( $host, $username, $password );
if (! $conn )
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db( $db_name );

// Submitting query and retrieving result)
$myusername = $_GET['myusername'];
$mypassword = $_GET['mypassword'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE usrName='". $myusername ."' and pwd='". $mypassword ."'";
$result = mysql_query( $sql );

// Checking results
$count = mysql_num_rows( $result );

// Directing user based on result
if ( $count == 1 )
{
```

Now down below is where I have actually set the session variable that I want to access later on.

```
    $userID = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result );
    $_SESSION['user'] = $userID['msgID'];

    header('Location: http://potholio.csproject.org/map.html');
}
else
{
    echo "<script>alert('Incorrect username or password');</script>";
    header('Location: http://potholio.csproject.org/');
}

// Close Database Connection
mysql_close();
?>
```

Now what I'm trying to access that session variable that I have set in a different file called map.html using the following code:

```
<?php
// Initiate session 
session_start();

// Store session data
echo $_SESSION['user'];

?>
```

The issue is that when I echo to see whether it was being set, the echo actually doesn't return anything, so I'm not sure what's going one since I know the variable is getting set in the other file, which is login.php. Any help with this probably would be great. I'm a complete beginner with Sessions and Session variables.

Comment: strange... do `var_dump($userID['msgID'])` or `var_dump($_SESSION['user'])` right after you assigned it.

Comment: yeah teh sessioning looks ok, what's inside msgID?

Comment: are you working on the same domain...are you trying to change window.location for php header() ?

Comment: @JeffHawthorne is just an auto increment value in my database table for the users.

Comment: @RobertRozas what do you mean exactly? Once the information that the user has entered matches the information thats in the table i redirect them to the main page of the website.

Comment: I mean http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php , to redirect on your pages, you are redirecting via javascript....

Comment: oh, i see. I guess let me try and set if that will change anything

Comment: yea that didn't change any results either.

Comment: In simple terms, it should work. The problem is not here, it is something else. You must be missing something somewhere. Are you overwriting it somewhere else, have you tried naming the session?

Comment: @vector Well i know its not getting overwritten any where else, at least i'm pretty sure it isn't, since it only have the session stuff in those two file right now. Also I'm not sure how to name the session. like i said i'm a noob with this

Comment: is missing quote `'` at the end of `header('Location: http://potholio.csproject.org/);` a typo?

Comment: oh yea i saw that @Amir and i fixed it but that's not the issue I just typoed here but not actually in my code.

Answer (score 1):

You are connecting in `localhost` , but your `header redirect` is `header('Location: http://potholio.csproject.org/map.html');`
It seems you are redirect to `map.html` from a different remote host, so how do you expect it keeps your localhost session?

Comment: i see, so then instead of redirecting to http://potholio.csproject.org/map.html, i should redirect to http://localhost/map.html?

Comment: Yes,surely you should go to `map.html` of your local

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I just figured out what my issue was. I found out that all the code I had was indeed correct and there was not any issues with what I had, except for how I was redirecting pages.

Thanks @Robert Rozas.

My problem was actually a really dumb and easy fix that I over looked. The PHP script on my map.html file was never being executed, because it was an HTML file and not a PHP file. Once I realized that and renamed the file so it had a .php file extension everything ran correctly. Sorry for the trouble guys, I should have seen that.

Comment: you can use map.html to run php code if you add following code in .htaccess file "AddType application/x-httpd-php .html". This piece of code will tell web server to treat html as php file.

Answer (score -1):

use `var_dump($_SESSION['user'])` instead of echo `$_SESSION['user']` for better detailed output.

Comment: yea just now tried using var_dump() instead of echo and I still got nothing to output on the page to see whether it was grabbing the session variable that was set in the login.php script